# How Can I Prevent Webform Being Displayed in Front Page

Tags: 7, webforms

I've installed panopoly distribution and Webform module. I've also created a webform called contact form and added the contact form in a pane as a block. The problem is: The contact Form (webform) is being displaying in the front page as new content.

I've also tried various settings including:

- Untick all options from publishing option (Administration » Structure » Content types » Webform)

to remove that but nothing works.

How can I remove webform from being displayed in the front page in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. There is a operation in panopoly called `Demote from front page` in `Administration » Content`.

[image]

This operation works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

The publishing options at Administration » Structure » Content types » Webform are defaults. Edit the particular webform node and uncheck "Promoted to front page".

Comment: Yeah I also did that, But nothing changed...